# In adapter I need to put array of parsed data i.e. If I pass like MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter (new String[]{"LOndon","NYC"}); it gets passed

Tags: android

In adapter I need to put array of parsed data i.e. If I pass like

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"LOndon","NYC"});
```

It gets passed. But parsed array `xyz` is not getting passed in Adapter.
From adapter I need to display data in `RecyclerView` and `CardView`. How to pass the parsed data through `Async`.

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public String[] xyz;
    RecyclerView rv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new http().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

       final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        //RecyclerView rv;
        rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        return rootView;
    }

    class http extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {

        public String xxx="";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10");

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                 String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String finalJson = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("value");
                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = jsonObject.getString("joke");
                    xxx += name ;

                }
                return xxx;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            String data = xxx;
            xyz = " ".split(xxx);
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(xyz);

            rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you misunderstood the [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method from `String`. In a few words the syntax looks like this: `stringToSplit.split(divider)` not as you wrote it: `divider.split(stringToSplit)`.
Fix the problem by changing `xyz = " ".split(xxx);` with `xyz = xxx.split(" ");`.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful and please check the comment from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216194/3734172

Answer (score 0):

In your MyAdapter add this

```
public MyAdapter(String[] xyz){
  this.xyz=xyz
}
```

**Edit**:

I slightly modified your code.Check is it works.

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

public String[] xyz;
RecyclerView rv;
MyAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new http().execute();

}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,   container, false);

   //RecyclerView rv;
    rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(xyz);
    rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return rootView;
}


   class http extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {


        public String xxx="";


   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;


        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10");

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
             String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("value");
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = jsonObject.getString("joke");
                xxx += name ;


            }
            return xxx;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String data = xxx;
        xyz = " ".split(xxx);
        mAdapter.addItems(xyz);//Create a method in the adapter
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
}}
```